# RDFa / Microformat - Recipe markup standards

Tags: microformats, rdfa, recipe, microdata

I wonder if anyone can help?

[After Google announced](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173379) that it will take note of RDFa / Microformats for online recipes, I've been looking into this for a couple of recipe based sites I run. However we simply don't have all the required data to fulfill any of the standards.

Does this matter? Will search engine crawlers still make the most of what they do find, or by missing a few elements (like a review or recipe rating) will I be wasting my time implementing this?

Also, if, for formatting reasons, I have to add extra divs around the information, does that invalidate it all?

Cheers, 
H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look to [hRecipe](http://microformats.org/wiki/hrecipe) draft specification.

The hRecipe schema consists of the following properties:

```
* hrecipe
      o fn. required. text. the name of the recipe.
      o ingredient. required. 1 or more. text with optional valid (x)HTML markup.
            + value and type. optional. [experimental] 
      o yield. optional. text.
      o instructions. optional. text with optional valid (x)HTML markup.
      o duration. optional. 1 or more. text.
      o photo. optional. 1 or more. using any element containing a URL, such as IMG. [experimental]
      o summary. optional. text. [experimental]
      o author. optional. 1 or more. [experimental]
      o published. optional. [experimental]
      o nutrition. optional. 1 or more. [experimental]
            + value and type. optional. [experimental] 
      o tag. optional. 1 or more. [experimental]
```

If you look at required fields `fn` and `ingredient` are mandatory, the others fields are optional.
The following example is a valid hRecipe recipe:

```
  <div class="mydivclass1">
   <h1 class="fn">Spaghetti al ragù</h1>
     <div class="myfancydiv2>Ingredients:</div>
   <span class="ingredient">
      spaghetti
   </span>
   <span class="ingredient">
      ragù
   </span>
 </div>
```

To check your microformats, you could use the cool [Optimus validator](http://microformatique.com/optimus/?format=validate&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F130929%2Fsystempuntoout).

Comment: Hmm, I didn't look on the schema. Interesting that Google doesn't list the `ingredient` property as required. Also notable that the Google specs contain properties that are not in the microformat schema published on microformats.org, such as `prepTime` and `cookTime`. Seems like Google is using its own schema which is based on the microformats.org one.

Comment: Google seem to be supporting 3 formats, I guess the main question is which will become "standard", if any of them do! Thanks for your help, I think it's clear I can mix it up a bit in the code without fear of not getting indexed!

Answer (score 1):

The only "must have" tag is the name of the recipe, the `fn` class if you go with microformats. This however must be the child of a parent which has the `hrecipe` class name to help the indexers distinguish between the special data and standard text.

BUT! The support for this was just released and I can't tell you if including only the recipe name will help you in any way; since it's a matter of a few changes, you probably want to test it on a site, wait a few weeks and apply to the rest of the sites if it works.

Regarding the extra DIVs, it shouldn't make any difference.